# How can I create my own component for FormControls?

Tags: forms, angular

I would like to create a form and use a new, custom component for its controls. So I created a new component and included it into the parent form. But although the parent form has a formGroup, Angular complains that it does not.

The error:

> Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.
>   You'll want to add a formGroup
>          directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

The parent form has:

```
<form [formGroup]="learningObjectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div>
    <button type="submit"
            [disabled]="learningObjectForm.pristine">Save</button>
  </div>

  <ava-form-control [label]="'Resource'"></ava-form-control>

</form>
```

And in the .ts:

```
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.learningObjectForm = this.fb.group({
      text: '',
    });
  }
```

In the custom component I have

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }       from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ava-form-control',
  template: `  <div>
    <label>{{label}} :</label>
    <input formControlName="{{name}}">
  </div>
`
})
export class FormControlComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() name: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.name === undefined) {
      // turns 'The Label' into 'theLabel'
      this.name = this.label[0].toLowerCase().concat(this.label.slice(1));
      this.name = this.name.split(' ').join('');
      console.log(this.label, this.name);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: does this help? https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/07/27/custom-form-controls-in-angular-2.html

Comment: you need to crete a custom component without `formControlName` directive, it needs to be applied on your custom component like <ava-form-control [label]="'Resource'" formControlName=''somecontrol" ></ava-form-control>, not inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also be passing the `formGroup` instance along with `control name` to your `custom component`. And then create a `form control` under that `formGroup` in custom component. Your custom component will create the control virtually under the same formGroup that you have provided.

```
<form [formGroup]="learningObjectForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" novalidate>
  <div>
    <button type="submit"
            [disabled]="learningObjectForm.pristine">Save</button>
  </div>

  <ava-form-control [label]="'Resource'" [formGroup]="learningObjectForm" [controlName]="'mycontrol'"></ava-form-control>

</form>
```

custom.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit }       from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ava-form-control',
  template: `  <div>
    <label>{{label}} :</label>
    <input [formControl]="formGroup.controls[controlName]>
  </div>
`
})

export class FormControlComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() label: string;
  @Input() formGroup: FormGroup;
  @Input() controlName: string;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    let control: FormControl = new FormControl('', Validators.required);
    this.formGroup.addControl(this.controlName, control);
  }
}
```

With this your parent component can access all the form controls defined within their respective custom components.

Comment: if formName is a string, why would it have the method addControl?

Comment: @LynHeadley Yes, you are correct. It has to be FormGroup. Updated.

Comment: So formGroup would be a better name than formName? And in your description, it is not quite right to say: "You should also be passing the name of the form" ?

Comment: Yes.. apology here.. I will update it to be form group instead of form name. That's not appropriate terminology.

Comment: Yes, I'm still working on this. I'll accept it when I confirm it works for me. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

I played around with the accepted answer for a long time, and never had any luck.

I had much better results implementing the ControlValueAccessor interface as shown here:
https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/

It's actually pretty simple, I also rigged up an [Example StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-controlvalueaccessor)