# Re-usable component values carry forward to page2/ any other page

Tags: angular, typescript

I have component  `search-component` like below html snippet

```
 <form class="form-horizontal form-material" (ngSubmit)="Search()" id="carsearch" [formGroup]="bookCarForm"
      novalidate>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm search-input-align">
          <input [owlDateTime]="dt1" [min]="min" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" class="form-control" formControlName="start_datetime"
            placeholder="Start Date & Time">
          <owl-date-time #dt1></owl-date-time>
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-search-align"></i></span>
        </div>

        <div class="col-sm search-input-align">
          <input [owlDateTime]="dt2" [min]="min" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt2" class="form-control" formControlName="end_datetime"
            placeholder="End Date & Time">
          <owl-date-time #dt2></owl-date-time>
          <span class="input-group-addon "><i class="fa fa-calendar "></i></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm search-input-align">
          <div class="toggle" (click)=toggleTextBox()>
            <input type="checkbox" class="check" >
            <b class="b switch"></b>
            <b class="b track"></b>
          </div>
          <h4 id="door-delivery">Door Delivery</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm search-input-align address">
          <div *ngIf="!visability">
            <input class="form-control " formControlName="Enter_address" type="text" placeholder="Enter Address"
              >
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="visability">
            <select formControlName="p_location" class="form-control selectpicker" id="select-city" >
              <option data-tokens="" disabled>
                <h2>select any one </h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="Delhi">
                <h2>Hebbal</h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="Mumbai">
                <h2>Yelahanka</h2>
              </option>
              <option data-tokens="hyderabad">
                <h2>BTM</h2>
              </option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm search-input-align btn-book-now">
          <button type="submit" [disabled]="bookCarForm.invalid" class="btn btn-primary align-items-center btn-align">Book
            Now</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

and in `search-component.ts` like below

```
@Output() searchValues = new EventEmitter(); 
this.storage.set("values", this.Search.value);//storing values in local storage
this.searchValues.emit("values");
```

this `search-component` is reusable. Currently I'm this form in `Page1` selecting values in `page1` and redirecting to `page2`. In the page2 also I'm using this form. What are all the values given in page1 this is should be carry forward to page2. So that I tried Event `Emitter`  but it is not carry forward values. 
[I tried this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47813940/angular-4-own-form-element-component), but it is not help me out. What is the best way to achieve this output. Could any one help me out.

Comment: You could use a shared service and persist the search value there.

Comment: how to do, any example please

Answer (score 1):

Create the following service **stored-data-service.ts**:

```
import {Component, Injectable} from 'angular2/core'
import {BehaviorSubject, Observable} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class StoredDataService {
  values:any;
  values$:BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject('');
  constructor(){}

  setValues(values){
   this.values = values;
   this.values$.next(values);
  }
}
```

Then add it to your **app.modules.ts** by importing it

```
import { StoredDataService } from "./stored-data-service.ts";
```

and then adding it to the providers array in the NgModule

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ...],
  imports: [
  ...],
  providers: [
  StoredDataService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Now inject it in your component `search-component.ts` by adding it to the constructor like this:

```
constructor (public storedDataService: StoredDataService){}
```

and finally use it to add data by doing

```
this.storedDataService.setValues(this.Search.value);//storing values in local storage
```

and to retrieve the data anywhere in your code (even in other components or services, thats the trick) you will need to subscribe to values$:

```
 const subscription = this.storedDataService.values$.subscribe( (values) => {
 //set a local variable here storing values in you component
 //...
 this.values = values
 console.log (values);
})
```

If you are going to use service StoredDataService again in another component remember to inject it in the constructor as before and to subscribe to the values$. Every time any part of your code invokes storedDataService.changeValues(...), anywere where you subscribed the callback of your subscriptor will be executed giving you the new value.

**EDIT**

**I changed the code to add BehaviorSubject and subscriptions, otherwise it will not work**

Comment: I realise that to do this better you could also use observables, to notify the different parts that the stored data has changed. Here you have a link to see how it goes: https://www.lucidchart.com/techblog/2016/11/08/angular-2-and-observables-data-sharing-in-a-multi-view-application/

Comment: everything works fine but values are not displaying in page 2 input fileds

Comment: Sorry I updated the answer. You will need to use Subjects and subscribe. Then you retrieve the new value in the callback every time it changes.

Comment: Also, you'll need to make sure the service is injected as a Singleton. Actually, that's Angular default behaviour for standard dependency injection of services in the same module (in the [providers] section of the Angular module config). Otherwise, be careful if you use several modules and/or custom dependency injections!

Comment: Yes, @Pac0 in the code above I added the service it in the providers NgModule of app.module.ts. It is true that if you are managing several modules you will have to take care of that in the different modules.

Comment: at present I'm outside, I will look into it and let you know if it is working or not

Comment: Ok, @change need, if you found the answer helpful, could you please mark it as accepted for the time being ?. It would be appreciated ;).