# What is the correct way to add a custom component to a reactive form's FormGroup?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am having a lot of problems using formControlName on a custom component wrapping an mat-select.

Now it appears that my custom control cannot find the form group?  Even though the custom element is nested under the formGroup.

I have a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-formcontrolname?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

But the problem comes in when I nest my custom component under the formGroup, all of the other controls can find the formGroup but my custom component doesn't seem to be able to.

```
<form novalidate [formGroup]="tenantForm">
    <label for="Id">Id</label>: <input class="form-control" formControlName="id" id="Id" name="Id" />
    <custom-component-with-mat-select formControlName="culture" id="Culture" name="Culture"></custom-component-with-mat-select>
</form>
```

In this example the Id field would work properly, but the Culture field complains about not being nested in a FormGroup?

**Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).**

How should a custom component work with reactive forms and form group?

My original problem was not remembering to import the ReactiveFormsModule..  Maybe I'm forgetting to import something again?

Is this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46002485/how-can-i-create-my-own-component-for-formcontrols) the designed way to accomplish this?  Or am I missing a simplier solution??

Do I need to implement a control value accessor??
As explained [here](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-form-control/)

just confused on the designed way to do this.

my component wraps angular material's mat-select, and I guess I'm also confused if I need to put attributes on the mat-select or have my component implement the control value accessor?  nothing seems to be working.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the binding of `formControlName`? Your stackblitz looks to be working with reactive forms.

Comment: Well your code works perfectly fine with formControlName="{{name}}" and name variable 'animationType'. I saw no error while editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some research and got it working with the control value accessor:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-select-with-controlvalueaccessor

Comment: He told you that he is trying to use a wrapper of the normal input. So this solution actually does not fix the issue he mentions. The solution below though, actually fixes the issue

Answer (score 3):

I solved that problem using the parameter 'formControl' instead of 'formControlName' like this:
**input-date.compoenent.html**

```
<p-calendar [formControl]="control"></p-calendar>
```

**parent.component.html**

```
<input-date [control]="formGroup.controls.date"></input-date>
```

Where control is an input of input-date.component:

```
@Input() control: FormControl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Control `formControlName` must be string value.

### Case 1

```
formControlName="animationType"
```

This working since `animtationType` is string value here.

### Case 2

```
[formControlName]="'animationType'"
```

This is throwing error since Angular is evaluating the value of `animationType` which is an array (defined in ts file)

### Case 3

```
formControlName="{{animationType}}"
```

This is failing as same reason as case 2

### Fix

If you want to access the formControlName then use string value in ts
ex :

** in ts **

```
public animationControl = "animation";
```

** in html **

```
<mat-select name="animationType" [formControlName]="'animationControl'"
```